# python 3 using for loops and typecasting

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

How can I get 2nd `for` loop the full aws ec2 instance id? It converts it to string it seems.

I am using Python 3.9.

1st loop gives output as expected:

```
i-0dccf1ede229ce1
i-0285506fee62051
```

2nd loop gives

```
i
-
0
d
c
...
```

```
INSTANCE_ID = ['i-0dccf1ede229ce1','i-0285506fee62051']
for i in INSTANCE_ID:
  print (i)
```

vs.

```
for i in INSTANCE_ID:
  for j in i:
    print (j)
```

Actual boto3 script is as below

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3


AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
AWS_PROFILE = "xxxx"
session=boto3.session.Session(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE)
EC2_RESOURCE = session.resource('ec2', region_name=AWS_REGION)
INSTANCE_ID = ['i-0dccf1ede229ce1','i-0285506fee62051']

TAGS = [
    {
        'Key': 'STATE',
        'Value': 'LIVE'
    }
]



for instance_id in INSTANCE_ID:
    for ec2_id in     instance_id:
      print (ec2_id) ## here is the issue 
      
      filter = EC2_RESOURCE.instances.filter(InstanceIds={ec2_id})
      filter.create_tags(Tags=TAGS)
```

Comment: It doesn't convert it to a string. It already *is* a string. The better question is: What do you *want* it to be, if not a string? It's clearly not an integer (they both start with `i` and have letters in the middle). If you stripped off the `i-` then I suppose you could parse it as a base-16 int, but that's something you have to go out of your way to do. Python isn't going to make those several leaps of logic without your help.

Comment: Your first loop already gives you the instance id. what do you want a 2nd loop for ?

Comment: Sorry if i am not able to express the desired output, in short the 2nd loop i would like to have the output same as 1st loop, is there any way i can achieve that ?

Comment: I dont understand why you want it then. Just use only one loop. Your first loop goes over each string in `INSTANCE_ID` list. Your second loop loops over each letter in the string obtained from first loop. You dont need the 2nd loop.

Comment: Yes, by not using the second loop.

Comment: Why do you think you need two loops? What's wrong with the first chunk of code you showed us?

Comment: So just use `for ec2_id in INSTANCE_ID`.

Comment: I need 2nd loop as the i have to use create a varible filter which takes 1 instance id at a time , so pulling one from array ..

Comment: "pulling one from array" is *exactly* what the first loop is doing. That's the *point* of a `for` loop, and you only need one to do it.

Comment: Here is the code from internet [link]https://hands-on.cloud/working-with-ec2-instances-using-boto3-in-python/#Adding-Tags-to-EC2-instance 
To make it work in few instance will need array

Comment: I really don't know how many other ways to say it. The code you've linked there *literally* has one `for` loop in it. There's nothing there that says "nested loop". Just one loop to iterate over an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. Still its not clear why 2nd loop what it does.

So i modified the code with 1 loop & indeed worked

@silvio & everyone thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3
AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
AWS_PROFILE = "xxx"
session=boto3.session.Session(profile_name=AWS_PROFILE)
EC2_RESOURCE = session.resource('ec2', region_name=AWS_REGION)
INSTANCE_ID = ['i-0dccf1ede229ce1','i-0285506fee62051']
TAGS = [
    {
        'Key': 'STATE',
        'Value': 'LIVE'
    }
]

for instance_id in INSTANCE_ID:
  print ( instance_id )
  instances  = EC2_RESOURCE.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
  instances.create_tags(Tags=TAGS)
```